# The kind literal in Haskell

Tags: haskell

As I know, the `->` has kind `*->*->*`, and the `((->) r)` has kind `*->*`.

Assuming there is a type `(a->b->c)`, is there a way to represent the `(a->b->)`?

I tried `((->) a ((->) b))` but it's error.

I tried:

```
type Kab a b c = (a -> b -> c) -- it is ok
```

But it is failed to use the `Kab` in instance declaration:

```
instance KClass (Kab a b) where -- error
```

The only way I found that works is declare a `data`:

```
data Kab a b c = Kab (a -> b -> c)
instance KClass (Kab a b) where ..
```

But if I use the data, I have to unwrap the `Kab`, while my idea is to implement a KClass on native function type.

So how to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can't be done, unfortunately.

One might wish for "type-level lambdas" (let's write them `/\`); then you would be able to write `forall a b. /\c. a -> b -> c` to denote this. This would be a really handy feature, and there has been much study into type systems that allow this, but the price you pay is that type inference becomes undecidable. So the Haskell committee decided to skip it.

Comment: *So the Haskell committee decided to skip it.* Could you add some reference for that?

Comment: @Jubobs I'm not sure exactly what you want to see here. There are no type-level lambdas in the Report; but it's not like there's a specific section they're not in or something like that.

Comment: Type inference with type lambdas is decidable for Miller's pattern fragment, which includes all the things we have with current Haskell type constructors. I think it's better to say we don't have type lambdas in Haskell because there hasn't been much need for it and dependent typing has been an experimental design space for until recently.

Comment: @DanielWagner "the Haskell committee decided to skip it" implies that some discussion took place; I was wondering if there was a trace of that discussion, perhaps on a mailing list...

Comment: @AndrásKovács Interesting; [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/185439/63596) seems to agree with me, though it doesn't cite its claims either. I can't seem to find a citation on Google Scholar that actually proves this one way or the other; perhaps you have a reference in mind?

Comment: @Jubobs I don't have a reference to a mailing list or anything like that. The best evidence I can offer is that I have worked for several years with some of the people that were on the committee and can attest to the depth of their expertise and broad knowledge of these kind of type system questions.

Comment: @DanielWagner: I don't have a reference, it was just my snap judgement:). I thought a bit more about it, and I think my point basically still stands if we add type lambdas but restrict instance heads to type constructors  (as it is the staus quo). Then the type checker can assume that a value with type (something -> Constraint) must be a type constructor, and then we can deduce (f ~ g, a ~ b) from (Functor f, Functor g, f a ~ g b), for example.

Comment: @DanielWagner: type functions in instance heads imply incoherent instances anyway, which may or may not be an acceptable tradeoff, but I don't really have space to expound these matters here.

Comment: @AndrásKovács You don't even need the excitement of type classes to make type-level lambdas exciting. Suppose you have `a :: ta` and `b :: tb`. Then type-checking the term `[a,b]` involves finding a substitution for all the free variables in the lambda-calculus term `ta` and a substitution for free variables in the lambda-calculus term `tb` that makes the two terms alpha-beta equal. That's higher-order unification, and it's known undecidable.

Comment: Haskell type inference has been undecidable for years. The stable door's open; the horse has bolted for better things. The question is not whether we need type annotations but how many, how big, and where? You can get a long way with explicit type signatures on definitions, from which information propagates inwards. The real kicker for Haskell is that the "type constructor class" machinery hangs off the "fact" that function application is injective: types are a first-order syntax. The shift to actual functional programming seems like just too much of a lurch!